# how to decide between choosing different types of containers?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, arm

I am writing a software for an embedded platform (ARM11) that runs Linux. This software is supposed to work for prolonged periods (months) of time without being closed / reopened and with mostly every embedded platform the RAM is scarce (250 Mega Bytes total for OS and user programs). This device is connected to another device through serial port and they communicate together continuously (every 300 milliseconds) in form of a ping for status, errors, alarms etc. This device is used for access control on a gate in a high traffic area where over hundred people will cross it using MIFARE cards as a means of identification. I thought about using dynamic containers to hold objects that hold communication packets and card data (because they can have different size from a few bytes to one kilo bytes) of-course this objects will be constantly created and destroyed and they won't stay for a long time (withing a function scope). My language of choice is C++ and I'll be using Qt for the libraries. also all the elements of data are unsigned 8 bit characters.

- won't using such containers cause memory fragmentation problem?
- since the maximum size for the containers is known wouldn't it be better to use C type containers like arrays and structs for better performance?
- Is there a rule of thumb for choosing the appropriate containers?

**EDIT:**
mifare cards contain 1 kilo byte of memory (1024 bytes) that are divided to 16 sectors of 4 * 16 bytes blocks each. On a read operation a minimum of one block of data is returned and I will need to extract as low as one bit of information from this block and the way I search the data obtained from the contactless cards would be through parameter files supplied to my program that clarifies the mapping and masks of the card data.

Comment: What do you see as the specific downsides of C++ containers (as compared to raw C arrays)?

Comment: 1) It depends how you use them. If you use `std::vector` wisely, you wouldn't get more fragmentation than you would with C dynamically allocated arrays. 2) No, see 1). 3) Use vector unless you really need something else (often you don't.) Of course, if you know the size of the containers at *compile* time, and they are not huge, you may consider `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth C++ containers are more expensive on memory operations and usually slower. also if enough care is not taken memory fragmentation can cause my software to stop working or consuming all of the memory.

Comment: @MoKi: Are you sure?  Access to a `std::vector` should be identical to a raw array.

Comment: i know the maximum size (since that's a matter of hardware limitation) but the minimum is not known. how much of size is considered huge?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sorry i meant dynamic containers.

Comment: @MoKi: `std::vector` *is* a dynamic container.  Are you thinking of something like `std::list`?  (Indeed, this would definitely be more expensive, but it's not really a sensible replacement anyway.)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you need to achieve (what will you use these containers for?). All you've said is that you'll have some data, with an allegedly short lifetime, and no information on algorithms or access patterns.

Comment: If you say "X is slower", you need to specify two things: slower than *what*, and what exactly is X. Concerning your question, an `std::vector` with pre-allocated memory will have very little or no overhead compared to a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @Useless I've added some more info to the Description. I hope that clarify the purpose.

Comment: So when you read one or more blocks, do you need to keep them around? Or can you just evaluate access granted/denied immediately and then discard the data?

Comment: @Useless no the data is destroyed once the access is granted/denied but some information is stored in form of a file for logging and inspection later.

Comment: So what do you need containers for at all? What are you ever _containing_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge in these conditions is memory fragmentation. A major cause is mixing object sizes in allocations, and freeing them at different times. There are effective techniques to combat that.

For starters, if you have many small objects of a fixed size (say 28), a dedicated allocator for that size objects will help. It cannot cause real fragmentation itself, you just have a bitmap of free blocks and to allocate you can just pick the first free block.

For strings, it can make sense to round up their sizes, e.g. to a multiple of 2 and just pad out the data with `\0`. You can then have dedicated allocators for sizes 8/16/32/64/etc. You'll waste no more than 100% and in practice it's closer to 40% (depends on string length distribution). For short strings, use the small string optimization - check if `std::string`  and/or `QString` use it, if not using your own string type may be advisable.

C type containers such as a `malloc`'ed array typically do quite poor, precisely for the reason mentioned above: too easy to generate them in any random length. `std::vector`  typically grows in nice fixed increments. However, check if it rounds `reserve` requests up to sane amounts (power of 2, or multiple of 4KB, whatever is smaller). If not, you should.